# Python Lottery Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, number-guessing-game

How could I improve this code or make it more efficient?

```
import random

menu_check = True

# 'checker', compares userNums and winningNums to see if they have won or lost
def checker(userNums, winningNums):

    if userNums == winningNums:
        print ("\nCongratulations! You Win $100!\n")
        print ("Your numbers: ", userNums)
        print ("The winning lottery numbers are: ", winningNums, "\n")
    else:

        print ("\nSorry, you lose...\n")
        print ("Your numbers: ", userNums)
        print ("The winning lottery numbers are: ", winningNums, "\n")

# 'getUserNums', gets user numbers and puts into a sorted list    
def getUserNums():
    userNums = []

    for x in range(3):
        nums = int(input("Pick a number 0 through 9: "))
        if 0 <= nums <= 9:
            userNums.append(nums)
        else:
            input("Error! Invalid input. Press any key to continue...")
            nums = int(input("Pick a number 0 through 9: "))
            userNums.append(nums)

    return sorted(userNums)

# 'getWinningNums', creates a sorted list with random nums ranging from 0-9 with a range of 3 values
def getWinningNums():
    return sorted(random.sample(range(0,10), 3)) 

# 'menu', creates the main menu to choose game or exit program
def menu():
    print (30 * "-", "LOTTERY MENU", 30 * "-")
    print ("1. [Play Pick-3]")
    print ("2. Exit")
    print (75 * "-")

# 'main', calls the other functions
def main():
    userNums = getUserNums()
    winningNums = getWinningNums() 
    checker(userNums, winningNums)

#         
while menu_check:
    menu()
    choice = input("\nEnter your choice[1-2]: ")

    if choice == '1':
        print (23 * "-")
        print ("[Play Pick-3] selected!")
        print (23 * "-")
        menu_check = False
        main()

    elif choice == '2':
        print ("\nThanks for playing!\n")
        menu_check = False
    else:
        input("Error! Invalid input. Press any key to continue...\n")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much you assume out of your user, but logic in `getUserNums` isn't foolproof. For example if I input a letter instead of a number an execption will be thrown because `int()` expects a number. Also if I enter a number less than zero or greater than 9 TWICE it'll store a number that is outside your intended range. I'm not sure if you wanted that to happen or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### General comments

For the most part this is very good code imho. You have a clear and consistent style. I really like you have split your functions into logical functions. You are however missing writing a more pythonic style function, and parts of your code is very hard coded.

### Style

You have a very consistent coding style which is good. However you seem to use a #C naming convention and formating instead of a pythonic. You are using [camelCase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for variable names however in Python recommend `UpperCamelCase` for class names, `CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORES` for constants, and `lowercase_separated_by_underscores` for other names.

The golden standard for style in python is[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
It explains in  excruciating detail how to structure your code. I whole heartily recommend skimming through it and follow it.

### Semantics

[You should use the `if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) module in your answer. This allows you to reuse the functions for later, and is a great thing to always use.

The `getUserNums()` is a bit strange. If my input is incorrect, you raise an error. However the second time my input is incorrect it passes just fine. You could solve this using a `while` loop instead

```
def getUserNums():
    userNums = []

    while len(userNums) < 3:
        nums = int(input("Pick a number 0 through 9: "))
        if 0 <= nums <= 9:
            userNums.append(nums)
        else:
            input("Error! Invalid input. Press any key to continue...")
```

The second problem with the snippet above is that you can guess the same number more than once! A quick fix for this would be to replace `if 0 <= nums <= 9` with

```
if 0 <= nums <= 9 and nums not in UserNums
```

A third and final problem is that you'r program crashes if the input is not an integer. There are many solutions for this, a quick and dirty one is shown below

```
    nums = input("Pick a number 0 through 9: ")
    try:
        nums = int(nums)
    except:
        print("Sorry your input must be an integer!")
        continue
```

The `continue` keyword is important as it skips the remainder of the loop. What happens if you remove it?

You have repeated uses of print in the `menu()` function, (a better name would perhaps have been `print_menu()`). This can be solved as follows

```
 def menu():
    print (30 * "-", "LOTTERY MENU", 30 * "-",
          '1. [Play Pick-3]",
          '2. Exit',
           75 * "-")
```

### Magic numbers

Throughout your code we find what is called [Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). They are unique values with unexplained meaning or multiple occurrences which could (preferably) be replaced with named constants. For example the range of numbers or `30*'-'`. These should optimally be replaced with named constants.

In the code below I have changed your variable names, replaced all the magical numbers.  I have also made some small changes to your main function.

Lasly I made your `Error` messages more descriptive: `input("Error! Invalid input. Press any key to continue...")` Firstly what is the error? What was wrong with my input? Secondly it is strange to ask the user to press any key to continue.

### Code

```
import random

NUMBER_OF_PICKS = 3
MIN_PICK = 1
MAX_PICK = 11
WINNINGS = 100
OFFSETT = 4


# 'checker', compares userNums and winningNums to see if they have won or lost
def checker(userNums, winningNums):
    if userNums == winningNums:
        print ("\nCongratulations! You Win ${}!".format(WINNINGS),
               "\nYour numbers: ", userNums,
               "\nThe winning lottery numbers were: ", winningNums, "\n")
    else:

        print ("\nSorry, you lose...",
               "\nYour numbers: ", userNums,
               "\nThe winning lottery numbers were: ", winningNums, "\n")


# 'get_user_nums', gets user numbers and puts into a sorted list    
def get_user_nums():
    userNums = []
    while len(userNums) < NUMBER_OF_PICKS:
        nums = input("Pick a number {} through {}: ".format(MIN_PICK, MAX_PICK))
        try:
            nums = int(nums)
        except:
            print("Sorry your input must be an integer!")
            continue
        if MIN_PICK <= nums <= MAX_PICK:
            if nums not in userNums:
                userNums.append(nums)
            else:
                print("Error! You have already picked this number")
        else:
            print("Error! Your number was not in range")

    return sorted(userNums)


# 'get_winning_nums', creates a sorted list with random nums ranging from 0-9 with a range of 3 values
def get_winning_nums():
    return sorted(random.sample(range(MIN_PICK, MAX_PICK), NUMBER_OF_PICKS)) 


# 'menu', creates the main menu to choose game or exit program
def lottery_menu():
    name = ' '*int(OFFSETT/2) + "LOTTERY MENU"
    dotted = (OFFSETT+len(name))*'-'
    options = ["[Play Pick {}]".format(NUMBER_OF_PICKS), 
               "[Exit]"]
    print('{} \n{} \n{}'.format(dotted, name, dotted))
    for i, opt in enumerate(options):
        print(i+1, opt)
    print(dotted)


def play_pick_n():
    userNums = get_user_nums()
    winningNums = get_winning_nums() 
    checker(userNums, winningNums)


# 'main', calls the other functions
def main():
    lottery_menu()
    while True:
        choice = input("\nEnter your choice[1-2]: ")
        if choice == '1':
            string = "\n[Play Pick {}]".format(NUMBER_OF_PICKS) + "selected!"
            dotted = '\n'+ len(string) * "-"
            
            print(dotted,
                  string,
                  dotted)
            
            play_pick_n()
            break

        elif choice == '2':
            print ("Thanks for playing!\n")
            break
                         
        print("Error! Invalid input. Press any key to continue...\n")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

A small comment, but you have duplicated code here:

```
if userNums == winningNums:
    print ("\nCongratulations! You Win $100!\n")
    print ("Your numbers: ", userNums)
    print ("The winning lottery numbers are: ", winningNums, "\n")
else:

    print ("\nSorry, you lose...\n")
    print ("Your numbers: ", userNums)
    print ("The winning lottery numbers are: ", winningNums, "\n")
```

Since in either case you intend to print the user's numbers and the winning numbers, pull that out:

```
if userNums == winningNums:
    print ("\nCongratulations! You Win $100!\n")
else:
    print ("\nSorry, you lose...\n")
print ("Your numbers: ", userNums)
print ("The winning lottery numbers are: ", winningNums, "\n")
```

Now if you decide to change either of those, you change it in only one location.

Additionally, it's great that you're commenting each function - but those comments would be even better if they were [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).  For example:

```
# 'checker', compares userNums and winningNums to see if they have won or lost
def checker(userNums, winningNums):
```

Would become:

```
def checker(userNums, winningNums):
"""Compares userNums and winningNums to see if they have won or lost
@param userNums: description of userNums
@param winningNums: description of winningNums
"""
```

A docstring might be overkill for a small project like this, but since you're basically writing them anyways, you might as well put them where people will expect them (and where information on the function will be